# How to merge the contents of a nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects called `allLeads` which stores a `leadName` and `leadId` for each item in the array along with an item called leads which is another array of objects.

But currently how I am receiving data from my backend is that the leads array only stores one object at a time. I want to **merge this leads array** for each `leadId` and `leadName`.

How it is currently

```
const allLeads = [
  {
    leadName: "software development",
    leadId: 123,
    leads: [{ profile: "hello", url: "bye" }]
  },
  {
    leadName: "software development",
    leadId: 123,
    leads: [{ profile: "lets", url: "go" }]
  },
  {
    leadName: "business development",
    leadId: 234,
    leads: [{ profile: "dont", url: "try" }]
  },
  {
    leadName: "business development",
    leadId: 234,
    leads: [{ profile: "other", url: "side" }]
  }
];
```

How I want it to be

```
const allLeads = [
  {
    leadName: "software development",
    leadId: 123,
    leads: [{ profile: "hello", url: "bye" }, { profile: "lets", url: "go" }]
  },
  {
    leadName: "business development",
    leadId: 234,
    leads: [{ profile: "dont", url: "try" }, { profile: "other", url: "side" }]
  }
];
```

Comment: what fails in your code?

Comment: Nothing fails I just need to somehow format it from 1st to the 2nd version

Comment: use array's `reduce` function to merge `leads` property if lead id of item is the same. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 1):

```js
const allLeads = [
  {
    leadName: "software development",
    leadId: 123,
    leads: [{ profile: "hello", url: "bye" }]
  },
  {
    leadName: "software development",
    leadId: 123,
    leads: [{ profile: "lets", url: "go" }]
  },
  {
    leadName: "business development",
    leadId: 234,
    leads: [{ profile: "dont", url: "try" }]
  },
  {
    leadName: "business development",
    leadId: 234,
    leads: [{ profile: "other", url: "side" }]
  }
];
function handle(array) {
  let obj = array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur.leadId] = acc[cur.leadId] || {};
    acc[cur.leadId].leads = acc[cur.leadId].leads || [];
    acc[cur.leadId].leadName = cur.leadName;
    acc[cur.leadId].leadId = cur.leadId;
    acc[cur.leadId].leads.push(...cur.leads);
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(obj);
}
  console.log(handle(allLeads))
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Use `map()`, `new Set()`

We can build a unique id list, then add value to each of them.

```
const result = [...new Set(allLeads.map(x => x.leadId))].map(x => ({
  leadName: allLeads.find(y => y.leadId === x).leadName,
  leadId: x,
  leads: allLeads.filter(y => y.leadId === x).map(z => z.leads[0])
}));
```

```js
  const allLeads = [
    {
      leadName: "software development",
      leadId: 123,
      leads: [{ profile: "hello", url: "bye" }]
    },
    {
      leadName: "software development",
      leadId: 123,
      leads: [{ profile: "lets", url: "go" }]
    },
    {
      leadName: "business development",
      leadId: 234,
      leads: [{ profile: "dont", url: "try" }]
    },
    {
      leadName: "business development",
      leadId: 234,
      leads: [{ profile: "other", url: "side" }]
    }
  ];
  
  const result = [...new Set(allLeads.map(x => x.leadId))].map(x => ({
    leadName: allLeads.find(y => y.leadId === x).leadName,
    leadId: x,
    leads: allLeads.filter(y => y.leadId === x).map(z => z.leads[0])
  }));
  
  console.log(result);
```

---

2.Use `forEach()`

For each item, check if duplicated in id, do different operations for them.

```
const reuslt = [];
allLeads.forEach(x => {
  const item = reuslt.find(y => y.leadId === x.leadId);
  item ? item.leads.push(x.leads[0]) : reuslt.push(x);
});
```

```js
const allLeads = [
  {
    leadName: "software development",
    leadId: 123,
    leads: [{ profile: "hello", url: "bye" }]
  },
  {
    leadName: "software development",
    leadId: 123,
    leads: [{ profile: "lets", url: "go" }]
  },
  {
    leadName: "business development",
    leadId: 234,
    leads: [{ profile: "dont", url: "try" }]
  },
  {
    leadName: "business development",
    leadId: 234,
    leads: [{ profile: "other", url: "side" }]
  }
];

const reuslt = [];
allLeads.forEach(x => {
  const item = reuslt.find(y => y.leadId === x.leadId);
  item ? item.leads.push(x.leads[0]) : reuslt.push(x);
});

console.log(reuslt);
```

---

3.Use `reduce()`, `Object.values()`

Build an Object, finally transfer to the result Array.

```
const result = Object.values(allLeads.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const item = acc[cur.leadId];
  item ? item.leads.push(cur.leads[0]) : acc = { ...acc, [cur.leadId]: cur};
  return acc;
}, {}));
```

```js
const allLeads = [
  {
    leadName: "software development",
    leadId: 123,
    leads: [{ profile: "hello", url: "bye" }]
  },
  {
    leadName: "software development",
    leadId: 123,
    leads: [{ profile: "lets", url: "go" }]
  },
  {
    leadName: "business development",
    leadId: 234,
    leads: [{ profile: "dont", url: "try" }]
  },
  {
    leadName: "business development",
    leadId: 234,
    leads: [{ profile: "other", url: "side" }]
  }
];

const result = Object.values(allLeads.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const item = acc[cur.leadId];
  item
    ? item.leads.push(cur.leads[0])
    : (acc = { ...acc, [cur.leadId]: cur });
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Build one object with keys (As unique name, here we we need id + name combination) and values to agregation of leads elements. (if the key already exist, just push the leads to existing). 

Once the loop is over, just get he `Object.values` of above built object to get the values as an array.

```js
const update = data => {
  const res = {};
  data.forEach(item => {
    const key = `${item.leadId}-${item.leadName}`;
    if (!res[key]) {
      res[key] = { ...item };
    } else {
      res[key].leads.push(...item.leads);
    }
  });
  return Object.values(res);
};

const allLeads = [
  {
    leadName: "software development",
    leadId: 123,
    leads: [{ profile: "hello", url: "bye" }]
  },
  {
    leadName: "software development",
    leadId: 123,
    leads: [{ profile: "lets", url: "go" }]
  },
  {
    leadName: "business development",
    leadId: 234,
    leads: [{ profile: "dont", url: "try" }]
  },
  {
    leadName: "business development",
    leadId: 234,
    leads: [{ profile: "other", url: "side" }]
  }
];

console.log(update(allLeads));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a not-so-fancy solution, but a quite more scalable one.
Creating a new array where to push leads or update the existing.

```
merge = raw => {
    contains = (merged, leadName, leadId) => merged.leadName === leadName && leadId === merged.leadId;
    const merged = [];

    raw.forEach(lead => {
        const { leadName, leadId } = lead;
        const m = merged.find(mg => contains(mg, leadName, leadId));
        if (m) {
            m.leads.push(...lead.leads);
        } else {
            merged.push(lead);
        }
    });

    return merged;
};
```

Note, if leadId is unique, you can simply modify the `contains` method to match by Id.